# delete image layer in pdf and work on text layers only

Tags: pdf, ocr

I have a searchable pdf document. I would like to delete the image layer to work on the text layer only. How can I do it? Thanks in advance to those who will help me

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done?

Comment: hi, i tried with acrobat in: view> show / hide> navigation panel> layers but it doesn't report any layer: neither text nor image. thanks